# Datagridview loop through all from last row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DatagridView1` like this

```
 ------------------
 | Name   | Phone |
 | john   | 0000  |
 | joe    | 1111  |
 ------------------
```

My code is:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    MsgBox(row.Cells(1).Value)
Next
```

This code produces the `msgBox` with the data `0000 in 1st msgBox` and 
`1111 in 2nd msgBox` But I want the exact opposite of this, which is:

`1111 in 1st msgBox` and  `0000 in 2nd msgBox`

What should I have to do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `For` loop with `Step -1`:

```
For i As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
Next
```

If you prefer to use a `For Each` loop, then this should work too:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Reverse
    MsgBox(row.Cells(1).Value)
Next
```

Comment: Is this possible with `For Each` loop ?

Comment: Thanks, alot. This is really helpful.